# Tableau SUM of records is wrong after linking datasets

Tags: join, tableau-api

I have two datasets on Tableau. They are originally csv files that I import.

The first has this fields :

- Date
- Name
- Device

And the second one those :

- Date
- Name
- Device
- Keyword

In the columns I put the "SUM(Number of Records)" and in the rows I put the "Device". I am joining the two datasets by linking the "Name" and the "Date".

[image]

The first dataset has three different devices : 'desktop', 'mobile', 'tablet' and the second one has only 'desktop'. I get the SUM of records for the device of the 1st dataset only (the result is correct).

[image]

I am new in Tableau and I want to get the results from there. I know how to make it work in mysql by joining the tables but I want to learn dealing with Tableau only.

Comment: First learn to join tables into a single data source using Tableau. That's the most efficient and usually the best approach. Then learn about data blending (effectively client side left joins of aggregated query results from multiple sources). Data blending is useful, but can be complex or inefficient depending on the circumstances. Tableau uses the color orange to warn you when you are using fields from multiple sources to make sure that is your intent. Heed the orange warning. Start with joins, learn Tableau basic well. Then learn where data blending fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link the two data sources, it doesn't mean the **Number of Records** will have both results. From the image, I can see you used the field from the *Primary Data Source*, so naturally it'll only count those results.

What you're looking for is a *calculated field* containing both devices. In this case you have to link both data sources (as you did) and create a *calculated field* like this:

```
COUNT([Device]) + COUNT([Dataset 2].[Device])
```

Here you can see that we are actually adding the count of both **Devices** (the first field from *Dataset 1*, our primary data source, and the second from *Dataset 2*). *Remember: when referring a field from a secondary data source, you always need to indicate it in the formula.*

Use your new calculated field in the Columns section to get the correct numbers.